# React - Calling a function of all class instances in an array state stored in a ContextProvider

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, javascript-objects

I have a provider that stores and adds 'People' to a state. This state is then exposed to the rest of the application. Everything works as expected, however when I get the instances of the classes I am unable to call their function. It returns `undefined` whenever I try to call it. The code itself does not error, but also doesn't work. Do you have any insight as what might be going wrong?

Person class:

```
export class Person {
    private name: string;
    constructor() {
        this.name = uniqueNamesGenerator(config);
    }

    getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

}
```

The provider

```
export const PeopleProvider = ({ children }: PropsWithChildren) => {
    const [ people, setPeople ] = useState<IPerson[]>([]);

    const addPerson = () => {
        setPeople([ ...people, new Person() ]);
    };

    const getInstances = (): IPerson[] => {
        return people;
    };

    return (
        <PeopleContext.Provider value={{ addPerson, getInstances }}>
            {children}
        </PeopleContext.Provider>
    );
};
```

The component

```
export const Home = () => {
    const { addPerson, getInstances } = usePeople();

    const add = () => {
        addPerson();
    };

    const getNames = () => {
        const people = getInstances();
        console.log(people);
        console.log(people.forEach(p => p.getName())); // <==== undefined
    };

    return (
        <Grid container>
            <Grid item xs={2}>
                <Typography>Settings</Typography>

                <Button onClick={add}>add</Button>

                <Button onClick={getNames}>get names</Button>
            </Grid>

            <Grid item xs={10}>
                <Typography>Side</Typography>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    );
};
```

When looking in the console, all objects do have a name and a `getName` function in their prototype. Any idea what might be causing the undefined here?

Comment: arr.forEach does not return anything. Try console.log(people.map(p => p.getName()))  or people.forEach(p => console.log(p.getName()))

Comment: You're absoulutely right. I am gonna bash my head on the table... Feel free to make this your answer, i'll accept it instantly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the docs mentioned https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

`Array.prototype.forEach` returns `undefined`

Try using `map` method

```
console.log(people.map(p => p.getName()))
```

or with `forEach`

```
people.forEach(p => console.log(p.getName()))
```